# Pass appropriate "Previous Page" keystroke to currently focused application

Tags: c#, command

I'm developing some Accessability tools and I want to be able to send the application that has focus a "Go to the Previous Page" command.

I.E., if Windows Explorer has focus, passing the `Alt+Leftarrow` into the `SendKeys.Send()` function or if in a Powerpoint Presentation, it would send just the `Leftarrow` command.

Is there such a functionality or do I have to have a list of common applications and just work from that?

Comment: I think you mean `Left Arrow`.

Comment: Thanks :) It's still early...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to 'Standard' forward and backward commands would likely be [WM_APPCOMMAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with an lParam of APPCOMMAND_BROWSER_BACKWARD or APPCOMMAND_BROWSER_FORWARD.

It's still not guaranteed to work in every application, of course, but it should work for some.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is almost the same as for the undo/redo functions in an editor for example. What you need are two stacks of type `System.Collections.Generic.Stack<string>`. One undo stack with holds the previously visited pages and one redo stack. It works like this:

The user visits page 1.

Then page 2. Now push the actual page (page 1) on the undo stack.

The user visits page 3.  Now push the actual page (page 2) on the undo stack.

The user wants to go to the previous page. Pop a page (it will be page 2) from the undo stack and push the actual page (page 3) on the redo stack. Then display page 2.

If the user wants to go forward instead of backwards then do it the other way round: pop from redo and push to undo.

If the user navigates to a new page, you also must clear the redo stack, since it is not possible from now on to go forward.

You could also call the undo stack "backwards stack" and the redo stack "forwards stack".

Comment: You're misunderstanding his question.  He wants to send commands to other programs.

Comment: You are right. I thought It was about implementing a Go Backward/Forward mechanism. I leave my answer here, it might useful to others.

Comment: The Code Project article [Sending Keystrokes to another Application in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SendKeys.aspx) explains how to do it.

Comment: He's not asking how to send keystrokes; he's asking how to determine which keystrokes to send.

Comment: If this is the case, the question is not formulated very clearly. It sould read something like: "How do I know which keystroke is required by different applications? ...".

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, I'll modify the title.  Sorry for being unclear!

Comment: I fear that you will have to maintain a list of applications together with their keystrokes.